# What is the answer to the following limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is the answer to the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^k}{k!} \frac{(4N+2k-1)!(k+N-1)!}{k!(k+2N-1)!^2}$$

where $N> 1$.

Comment: Ok, have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: Then please consider provide the context.

Comment: @Leo Sorry, I don't understand what you mean about providing the contex?

Comment: You said that this is not homework, that the question arose when trying to solve a research problem, so, how was that? What were you working on? What is that problem? Why is enough to solve this one?

Comment: @leo Im an electrical engineer, I faced that while I was trying to proof a theorem about the diversity in Multiple antenna communication systems. I didnt say it is enough to solve this one! Answering this problem may or may not help me to accomplish the proof!

Comment: This is a mathematical problem. A limit of power series. I know it is a hard problem to be solved.

Comment: In that case, this pretty cool! I wonder why you didn't add all those details directly when posting your question (I encourage you to do so, it will make it a better question and will attract more attention which is good if one is hoping for answers). I guess you where trying to keep things concise. But in general, questions which provide more details about where they come from or how they arose are received better by the community. As example you can see this in the most up voted questions.

Comment: @leo Thank you so much:), I just wanted to keep it concise. So do you think its better to provide some infomation about the physics of the problem?

Comment: Indeed! Yes it is! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the limit is zero. At least when $N$ is an integer between 1 and 75. The series may be evaluated in terms of Bessel functions $I_0(2x),I_1(2x)$.

For example
$$
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k}{x}^{k} \left( 15+
2\,k \right) !\, \left( k+3 \right) !}{ \left( k! \right) ^{2} \left( 
 \left( k+7 \right) ! \right) ^{2}}}
=
\left(4194304\,{x}^{4}-15728640\,{x}^{3}+15335424\,{x}^{2}-4915200\,x-138240
-610560\,{x}^{-1}-698400\,{x}^{-2}-639360\,{x}^{-3}-432000\,{x}^{-4}-
172800\,{x}^{-5}
\right)e^{-2x}I_0(2x) +
\left(-4194304\,{x}^{4}+14680064\,{x}^{3}-11796480\,{x}^{2}+2359296\,x+
537600+760320\,{x}^{-1}+915840\,{x}^{-2}+914400\,{x}^{-3}+725760\,{x}^
{-4}+432000\,{x}^{-5}+172800\,{x}^{-6}
\right)e^{-2x}I_1(2x)
$$